# Where is Ning located during the quest "Rotten Business?"

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

In the quest "Rotten Business," you are able to bribe Chaunli into giving you the location of Ning.

[image: Unconscious Chaunli]

As you can see, I don't take well to people asking for my money.  Now the quest has no marker and simply tells me that I have to find her the hard way and that she's somewhere in the Daigong district.  Where in this district is she?  Pictures/maps are most appreciated.

Comment: you should post that map and the last bit of text as a self-answer. The currently accepted answer is a bit rubbish.

Comment: @DMA [Done](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29138/where-is-ning-located-during-the-quest-rotten-business/29152#29152)

Comment: @DMA I had thought so too.  As you can tell from the timestamp, I originally posted it as a self answer right when I figured it out.  Then, when I remembered that I couldn't accept my own answer right away decided I should just give the answer to something else.  I'll accept my self-answer when I'm able tomorrow (sorry @fredley!)

Comment: Asking me for money? That's a lethal takedown.

Comment: @Lunboks Technically, I did the non-lethal takedown.  Still, violence is always justified :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: Map]

For anyone having trouble with this, the exact location is down the stairwell immediately to the right of the player marker.  Thanks to [fredley's](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29138/where-is-ning-located-during-the-quest-rotten-business/29141#29141) answer and a little persistence, I was able to find it.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to find Ning without losing any money is to pay Chaunli and then kill/knock him out and loot his body to get the money back.

This way you have the marker and you don't lose any money.

Comment: It looks a bit late for that...

Comment: He could always reload a previous save. Unless he's saved after he knocked the guy out and also invoked two auto-saves.

Answer (score 3):

Ning can be found around the [Alice Pods apartments](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Alice_Garden_Pods).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up finding it after a bunch of desperate searching.

Comment: Ning isn't in the Alice Garden Pods section, and "around them" is horribly vague...